# Microsoft Hypervisor: Can we map LUNs directly to VM like VMWare RDM using HyperV's Virtual Fibre Channel Feature?

Tags: virtualization, hyper-v, fibre-channel

If we have a vSAN created on Microsoft Hypervisor and Virtual FC Ports have been assigned to VMs, can we directly map a LUN to the VMs bypassing the Hypervisor? i.e. The Hypervisor's disk management should not display these as Physical Drives.

The array is connected to the Hypervisor through an NPIV enabled switch and the Host adapter is also NPIV enabled.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should be able to do that. Good guide here:

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn551169%28v=ws.11%29.aspx

I'd still leave all the storage mgmt to hypervisor and deal with VHDX only. With shared VHDX, and major improvements around it in WS2016 you don't need raw access to FC anymore. IMHO.

Comment: I agree. With pass-through disks migration and backups may be quite problematic. Besides, pass-through is never much faster than VHDX, to say the least.

Comment: Yeah, we tested pass-through once and this was not the best idea. VHDX is doing well in WS2016.

Answer (score 2):

That's exactly what Virtual FC Ports do.  You give the VM some World Wide Names.  You unmask the LUNs to those WWNs.  Then they show up in the VM.  They do not show up in the host, which has different WWNs.